# Database schema is not generated in a EAR Application

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, java-ee-6, ear

I have this scenario in a EAR application which have the following structure:

- Project

  - data
  - ear
  - entity

    - META-INF

      - persistence.xml
  - business
  - web

At the entity folder there is all the entity classes and a persistence.xml with the hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto property setted to create. When I deploy the jar about entity the database is generated but when I deploy the ear he isn't. Please somebody can let me know why this is happening and some way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your EAR project you must have a `META-INF/application.xml` file, that includes the entity jar file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="6">
  <display-name>MY_ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>ENTITY.jar</ejb><!--change the name accordingly-->
  </module>
</application>
```

Comment: Thanks it works!
I was setting it as jar module, so as I changed to ejb module it already worked!